# Delphi: application running as admin does not receive messages from non-admin app

Tags: delphi, winapi, sendmessage, postmessage

I want to send messages to another application, using SendMessage/PostMessage, but when the other app is running as admin it never receives the messages. How can I overcome this without running the "sending" app as admin?

EDIT: code for Remi's answer, receiver app

```
Const dummyValue = WM_USER + 71423;

  Application.HookMainWindow(AppClass.AppHookFunc);
  ChangeWindowMessageFilter(dummyValue, MSGFLT_ADD);

Type TAppClass = class
  function AppHookFunc(var Message : TMessage): Boolean;
end;

Var AppClass: TAppClass;

function TAppClass.AppHookFunc(var Message : TMessage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  Case Message.Msg of
    dummyValue: begin
      // do stuff
      //
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is a common problem that has been covered here (and elsewhere) many times. Some websearch is all that is needed.

Comment: So, you want to access something you're not allowed to access? That's the whole purpose of elevated privileges. It's like asking how to sneak into the White House.

Comment: If you are running in Windows 7 or later, you really should be using `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` instead: `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(Application.Handle, dummyValue, MSGFLT_ALLOW, nil);`

Comment: @JerryDodge both apps are mine

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah I did, thanks, I check TOSVersion major/minor values, then use Ex if 7+, old one if Vista

Comment: @hikari That's not my point. Windows doesn't care whether they're both yours or not. It just knows there's two processes, one is elevated and the other is not.

Comment: @hikari if you need to support Vista and earlier, it would be safer to use dynamic loading at runtime to detect the presence of the `Ex` function and call it if available, rather than checking the OS version number. But ok, whatever works for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[User Interface Privilege Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation) (UIPI) prevents a lower integrity process from sending window messages to a higher integrity process.  The only ways you can deal with this limitation from a software perspective are to either:

- run your sending app at a higher integrity level (ie, run it with elevated privileges) to match the target process.
- if you have access to change the source code for the receiving app,  make it opt-in to receive specific window messages from lower integrity processes, by calling [`ChangeWindowMessageFilter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilter) or [`ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilterex) on itself.
- have your sending app bypass UIPI, by requesting `uiaccess=true` in its `<requestedExecutionLevel>` application manifest element. However, this has additional requirements:

  - The app must be digitally signed with a certificate that can be verified with a root certificate installed on the machine.
  - the app must be installed in a "secure" folder on the filesystem <sup>1</sup> (one that standard users can't write to) under `%ProgramFiles%` and its subdirectories, or under `%WinDir%` and its subdirectories (except a few subdirectories that standard users do have write access to).

    <sup>1: this requirement is [configurable via a system policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/user-account-control-only-elevate-uiaccess-applications-that-are-installed-in-secure-locations).</sup>

Outside of software control, the only other option available requires changing system policies to disable User Account Control (UAC) and/or UIPI altogether at the system level.  Which you should not do.

Comment: I can't get it working with either ChangeWindowMessageFilter or ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx. Added sample code

Comment: Actually it works if I get a msg with RegisterWindowMessage, thanks ( value must be within 0 - $FFFF)

Comment: @hikari `WM_USER + 71423` is `$11AFF`, which is WAY outside of the user-accessible range of messages (`$0400..$FFFF`), it is in the system reserved range of messages. The max `WM_USER + x` message you can define is `x = 31743` before entering the `WM_APP + x` range. `RegisterWindowMessage()` is the only way to define messages in the `$C000...$FFFF` range, and is the preferred way to define custom messages that cross process boundaries.